# Weird triangle on mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I seem to have a very weird pointer on my Samsung S22C200 22in monitor (second screen plugged into laptop).  I'm seeing a weird triangle/arrow next to my mouse.  I see it any time the mouse is not the pointer.

I tried to live with it for a couple hours this morning, but it's driving me nuts.

I've tried resetting my monitor settings to the default and that didn't fix anything.  I've unplugged from my laptop and that didn't do anything.  I've restarted my laptop and that didn't do anything.  I've Googled and didn't find anything.  I'm out of options.

I can't post an image (which is frustrating) because apparently I don't have the reputation, but it's just a small triangle next to the cursor...

Comment: Upload the image to an image sharing site and post the link, one of us will add it to your post.

Comment: Are you using a special mouse or mouse software other than the Windows drivers?

Comment: Have you tried setting the theme on Windows making sure to verify the mouse icons being used?

Comment: It's not a monitor problem. Monitor doesn't care about what's on the screen, in fact it doesn't even know what a cursor is - it's just showing a picture that comes in through the cable.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse icons currently in use can be found at Start--> Control Panel--> Mouse (icon view)--> Pointers tab.  That list should display your rogue icon.  You can change the icon from here as well.